# Password protected View in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have 1 view, `/lookup/{ID}` there is a box where some information is shown. If you create a lookup you can decide if you want to protect the lookup with a password or not.

So I'm checking on the `lookup` function in my PostController if the password in database is empty, if not I do `return view ('password')`, then its showing me the password view, which is how I wanted it. But now comes the tricky part:

If the password is correct I obviously want the user to show the information, thats why I do it like this:

```
if(Request::is('password')) {
   if(Hash::make($request->password) == $post->password) {
       return view('/lookup/' . $id);
   }
}
```

But when I enter the password it says `The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.`

My password and lookup view uses the same function: `lookup`

lookup is a `get` route and password is a `post` route

```
Route::post('/password/{id}', 'PostController@lookup');
Route::get('/lookup/{id}', 'PostController@lookup');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Hash::make($request->password) == $post->password` using `==` to *"verify"* password is a very bad idea.. You need to use a timing attack safe string save comparison function which does not short circuit when the first char already is a mismatch that way brute forcing can be used to attack the hash..

Comment: You should use [hash_equals()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php) instead off using `==`, that one is a timing attack safe string comparison function..   But that `Hash` class might provide a way for the used hash algorithm ..

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. Which probably is ```if (Hash::check('secret', $hashedPassword))``` in Laravel if I recall correctly?

Comment: *"Which probably is if (Hash::check('secret', $hashedPassword)) in Laravel if I recall correctly?"*.... But that Hash class might provide a way for the used hash algorithm, not sure how you hashed it

Comment: I hash it with ```Hash::make()```

Comment: *"I hash it with Hash::make()"* i didn't program with laravel framework for years ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can you use any parameter.

```
Route::any('/password/{id}', 'PostController@lookup');
```

Examples; https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing

İf you want this url except protect csrf token; edit except protected $except in app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php . Example

```
  protected $except = [
        //
        "/password/*"
    ];
```

Comment: It will output the same error ```The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. ```

Comment: instead of the password route, I have set my lookup view to any now, the error isnt coming, but it just refreshes the page when I enter either the incorrect or correct password.

Answer (score 0):

Which method are you using on the form to send the password? The error sort of indicates that you are posting to the lookup route... which is a get.

Comment: I have set the lookup route to any now and now the error is not coming, but if I enter the correct password it just refreshed the page.

I use post on the password view

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get what you meant by "I have set the lookup route to any now"

Comment: It looks like this: Route::any('/lookup/{id}', 'PostController@lookup');

Comment: I see. What does this route do? Route::post('/password/{id}', 'PostController@lookup');

Comment: Because from the look of it, lookup is the get request to load the view. So I think you should be posting to 'password' instead of 'lookup' to make pass that comparison logic.